# Unable to pre-set Radio button tied to null value

Tags: google-app-maker

I have a radio button:
Options: [null,"N","U"], displaying [All, New, Used] on the ui.

I can set the onAttach to widget.value = "N" or "U" and it works perfectly. If I set onAttach to widget.value = null, the UI has no selection.

How can I force the first option, "All" to always be selected onAttach?

Comment: I guess you may need to provide some additional information on your settings. I just tried this and set my nullitemname equal to All, set my options to ['N','U'] and set my onAttach event to widget.value = null. When I loaded my page the null -- All was pre-selected for me. So maybe share what your value binding is and what your options binding is so we can see if there is a problem elsewhere.

Comment: I guess looking at your question again, your options include null, so maybe remove that and make sure that allowNull is selected in the widget property editor.

Comment: Thank you, that worked! I missed the fact that the 'nullItemName' creates another option on the radio button widget.